# Mi lista no funciona

Tags: dev-c++, c++11

Estoy haciendo una lista que busca un numero dentro de un arreglo y lo vincula con su mes correspondiente. Se supone que para cada numero entre 1 y 12 que escriba tiene que mostrar su mes del año correspondiente, pero no lo hace.

```
int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
char Meses[12][30] = {"Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"};
int numero[12] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
int N;

cout<<"Ingrese un numero del 1 al 12: "; cin>>N;

while((N<1)||(N>12)){
    cout<<"El numero tiene que estar entre 1 y 12.\n Ingrese un numero otra vez: "; cin>>N;
} cout<<endl;

int iInferior=0; 
int iSuperior=11;
int iCentro=0; 
int i=0;
char bandera = 'F';

while(iInferior<=iSuperior){
    int iCentro=(iSuperior+iInferior)/2;
    if(numero[iCentro]==N){
        bandera='V';
        break;
    }
    if(numero[iCentro]>N){
        iSuperior=iCentro-1;
    }
    else{
        iInferior=iCentro+1;
    }
}

if(bandera=='V'){
    cout<<"El numero "<<N<<" corresponde al mes "<<Meses[iCentro]<<"."<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Pero cuando lo corro solo me vincula los numeros con "Enero", que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Es realmente _basic_?

Comment: Emmm, puse basic por nivel básico no?

Comment: _Basic_ es un lenguaje :) Pon en las etiquetas a qué lenguaje estás haciendo referencia.

Answer (score 1):

Hola te dejo una posible solución, veo que tratas de encontrar el numero ingresado atraves de un while, pero no seria mejor utilizar ese numero para buscar directamente en tu array meses?
por ejemplo:

```
cout<<"Ingrese un numero del 1 al 12: "; cin>>N;
cout<<"El numero "<<N<<" corresponde al mes "<<Meses[N]<<"."<<endl;
```

Y una observación. Porque tu arreglo Meses tiene estas dimensiones [12][30]?
si solo bastaría con Meses[12]

Espero y te sirva, saludos.

Comment: ¿Con qué lenguaje trabaja OP? Por cierto, si es C++, [30] es el tamaño de columna.

Comment: [30] es el numero de columnas.

Answer (score 0):

No modificas el valor de `iCentro`, dado que esta variable nace con valor cero siempre te muestra `Enero` porque cero corresponde a ese mes:

```
…

int iInferior=0; 
int iSuperior=11;
int iCentro=0; // Valor inicial, este valor no cambia.
int i=0;
char bandera = 'F';

…
```

El motivo por el que `iCentro` no cambia es porque en el bucle **creas una nueva variable** del mismo tipo y nombre:

```
…

int iInferior=0; 
int iSuperior=11;
int iCentro=0; // Variable 'iCentro' exterior.
int i=0;
char bandera = 'F';

while(iInferior<=iSuperior){
    int iCentro=(iSuperior+iInferior)/2; // NUEVA 'iCentro' sólo existe en el bucle.

    …

}

…
```

Si cambias la definición + inicialización por una asignación tu código funciona:

```
…

while(iInferior<=iSuperior){
    iCentro=(iSuperior+iInferior)/2; // Usamos la 'iCentro' externa.

    …
}

…
```

Pero estás matando moscas a cañonazos, puedes conseguir el mismo comportamiento con menos código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    const string Meses[12] {"Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"};
    int N;

    cout << "Ingrese un numero del 1 al 12: ";
    cin >> N;

    while ((N < 1) || (N > 12)) {
        cout<<"El numero tiene que estar entre 1 y 12.\n Ingrese un numero otra vez: ";
        cin >> N;
    }

    cout << "\nEl numero " << N << " corresponde al mes " << Meses[N - 1] << ".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHBTsMwDD03X2GFyyoxRAdcWFVpEkMCaeXAke2QZVaJ1LolTYa2sW8vbgNsEpf6@TXP78XRTTPWpaKi6y4M6dJvEFJTt86iqjJx4pgxVGRCGHJQKUOjWBxE5FtmgVSFbaM0Qus2UyEiXVPrIGhggS22b8lkBQc5J7S1vJSPuLYBLZTd93W2tqYc@l3fPnsyoZZDnRUcqgev2DiDFcu5edHOB5TX2z/2wegffJyKqA@ch1DeQZqCfKLCcibwBOQrjgEbLCEBxZ/JPUgWaUOQZUH3@W5KhNEohxSSGL6@gGHGR@MYeAXD3DSV8/J3GucjhA@PgK1TFpB4nTx/x5qrJcF//9pZBVvcB/Mz9@h4HnxJJxPZM/lAg64tD2xq4pfiS/BjhN9h8zmMIVkNJ9ld9ley6LwluJ6KY9cldyK5FcmNSCbiGw)</kbd>.